# How do I change the amount of items retrieved from a flickr feed?

Tags: json, api, rss, feed, flickr

Does anyone know the parameter to change (decrease) the amount of items retrieved in the flickr feed?

It always returns 20 items by default. Example:

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json

The documentation is rather scarce:

http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to control this from the flickr API, however, I did come up with another site which offers RSS of flickr feeds (precisely because the flickr API is limiting)

http://www.degraeve.com/flickr-rss/

Comment: Thx Nigel, although can not use it for my case.